# How can I find out, if type is created inside namespace?

Tags: c++, macros, type-traits

I have created Tag system, which allows tag entity in ma engine. It works based on c++ types, so every tag is a type (I have my reasons).

Now, when I want to create new tag, I have to call `struct tagname{};`.

If I want to use tag in other files, I use forward declaration `struct name;`

To make it more user friendly I created macros

```
#define CREATE_TAG(name) struct name{};
#define USE_TAG(name)    struct name;
```

But when user call one macro inside namespace and other outside namespace, I have a problem, because that are 2 different types.

I want to ensure, that user call macros outside any namespace. Since our project is in one namespace `namespace root`, I can use it for chcecking.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
namespace root
{
    const unsigned TAGS_CAN_NOT_BE_DEFINED_INSIDE_ANY_NAMESPACE = 1;
};

#define CREATE_TAG(name)    namespace root{  struct name{}; static_assert(root::TAGS_CAN_NOT_BE_DEFINED_INSIDE_ANY_NAMESPACE,"");  }
#define USE_TAG(name)       namespace root{  struct name;   static_assert(root::TAGS_CAN_NOT_BE_DEFINED_INSIDE_ANY_NAMESPACE,"");  }
```

Now when macro is used outside root namespace, everything is fine. When called inside root namespace or other nested namespaces, it gives the error `TAGS_CAN_BE... not a member`.

But I do not really like it. I don't like the whole macro thing, but that is not the question. Question is: Is there a better way to find out, if macro is called in namespace?
Since my macros passing in Type, I can use some typetraits, but I did not find any suitable one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks that

```
namespace root
{
    const unsigned TAGS_CAN_NOT_BE_DEFINED_INSIDE_ANY_NAMESPACE = 1;
};

#define CREATE_TAG(name)    namespace root{  struct name{}; static_assert(root::TAGS_CAN_NOT_BE_DEFINED_INSIDE_ANY_NAMESPACE,"");  }
#define USE_TAG(name)       namespace root{  struct name;   static_assert(root::TAGS_CAN_NOT_BE_DEFINED_INSIDE_ANY_NAMESPACE,"");  }
```

is the answer...

I will wait a few days before I accept it. I am still open to your answers

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#define DECLARE_ME(name) struct tag_##name { static_assert(!std::is_same<tag_##name, ::tag_##name>::value, "Not in global namespace"); }
```

You'll probably get a compiler-error that's not even the static assertion in case of a misuse, but it should catch the problem. You could probably make it more user-friendly with a more elaborate trait class.

Comment: thank you, but that other error message is exactly why I abandoned using is_same. I am getting `... is not a member of global namespace` ... that is why I used the crazy variable TAGS_CAN...

Comment: I see. But the error message would only appear if there was an error, and a correct program wouldn't be affected... but anyway, I actually think that this cannot be done. The preprocessor knows nothing about the language and does not interact with the scoping at all - it's merely a lexical search/replace tool. It's possible that your entire problem could be solved better with a different approach, though.

Comment: But if you think the question through is not really about the macro and preprocessor. It is about writing code, which can detect "if I (the code) am written in namespace". That code is then just wrapped into macro

Comment: @relaxxx: Nah, I think you're only asking that because you're already mentally committed to your macro. My personal impression here is that there should be a better solution that goes an entirely different route and can be done in C++ directly (or perhaps with a very minor macro only).

Comment: you are probably right :) I am sure there is a better solution. But originally it was done via macros, the used for some time (on a lot of places) and now a hidden problem comes up (type in napespace is dofferent). So I "have to" preserve CREATE_TAG and USE_TAG macros and provide checking functionality. Your solution is nice, but it doesn't give me the right error message I would like for users